# How do I monitor disk usage by processes over time?

Tags: disk-usage, monitoring

I can see my Ubuntu instance (on a cloud provider) averaging thousands of blocks per second, yet when I observe in real time it's hard to see which process is causing this.

Is there a monitoring command I can employ and let it run for an hour or so and then collect disk usage information (e.g. which processes were most active in this respect, or even which files)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can run `iotop` with the accumulated switch:

```
sudo iotop -a
```

See its [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/en/man1/iotop.1.html) for more options.